# How to connect telegraf to kafka at docker-compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, telegraf

I have at docker zookeeper, kafka, telegraf, influxdb, postgres and other

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    healthcheck:
      test: echo stat | nc localhost 2181
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:0.11.0.0
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      LOG4J_LOGGER_KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_LOGGER: TRACE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "testservise:1:1,testServiceInQueue:1:1,anotherTestServiceInQueue:1:1,storageServiceInQueue:1:1"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:latest
    container_name: influxdb
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "8086:8086"
      - "8090:8090"

  telegraf:
    image: telegraf:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: telegraf
    hostname: localhost
    links:
      - influxdb
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/.telegraf/telegraf.conf
```

First of all I do this
`telegraf -sample-config -input-filter kafka_consumer -output-filter influxdb > telegraf.conf`

Cause need to use telegraf /plugins/inputs/kafka_consumer 
Is it right docker-compose file?

After that I need to get out information from kafka, when my test service send something, how I can do it or how to right google it?

Answer (score 0):

Your compose file looks fine

By default, I believe the telegraf config looks like so

```
[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
    ## kafka servers
    brokers = ["localhost:9092"]
    ## topic(s) to consume
    topics = ["telegraf"]
```

You'll need to use `kafka:9092` and update the topics accordingly. And you'll need to also update the influx output probably away from localhost as well

You could also use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/influx.html) for writing kafka messages to InfluxDB

Comment: Thank you
Telegraf config looks the same